# How do you run a maven command that is the same as my IntelliJ Run config

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I normally run my Junit tests ( Selenium ) on IntelliJ's Run/Debug configuration : see image.

[image: screenshot]

Can someone point me to the right direction please on how to translate this into a maven command? Specifically invoking the `AcceptanceTestSuite.class`?

My goal is simple ( sorry if I can't figure it out ) To run that Maven command in Jenkins.

Tried using `mvn clean test` - it builds but it doesn't execute me tests.

Comment: I figured it out. ( For future references )

1. Go to your Jenkins Job
2. Add a build step
3. Invoke Top Level Maven Commands ( if youre using maven ) 
4. Add param in the `Goals` section.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. ( For future references )

1. Go to your Jenkins Job
2. Add a build step
3. Invoke Top Level Maven Commands ( if you're using maven )
4. Add param in the `Goals` section.

example

```
clean
verify
-Denv.config.file=qa1.properties
-Dmetafilter=+smoke
-Dadmin.login=1234
-Dadmin.password=1234
-Dserenity.jbehave.rerun.max.count=0
```